# Count incidents per year - output CSV QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, csv, expression

I have a points dataset of fire incidents, where each incident's date is recorded.

[image]

I am currently counting the number of incidents per year, by selecting features by expression - using the expression `ACQ_DATE LIKE '%2001%'` , `ACQ_DATE LIKE '%2002%'` etc for each year from 2001-2021.

I wish to do this automatically using one expression, which outputs a CSV that looks like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this expression. Normalle, if using field calculator, it calculates the same list (each year + number of entries per year) separately for each feature. To avoid that, simply select **one** feature and then run field calculator with the box checked next to `Only update 1 selected features`.

If your date is indeed formatted as `date` (not as text), instead of `left (ACQ_DATE,4)` you can use `year (ACQ_DATE)`.

```
replace (
    array_to_string (
        array_sort (
            array_distinct (
                array_agg (
                    left (ACQ_DATE,4)  || ': ' || 
                    array_length(
                        array_agg( 
                            to_int (left (ACQ_DATE,4)), 
                            group_by:=to_int(left (ACQ_DATE,4))
                    ))  || '\n'
    )))),
    ',',
    ''
)
```

[image]

Comment: When I click ok nothing happens? The counts appear in the preview however

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? Did you set `Output field type` to text (and make sure it's long enough)?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use a virtual layer :

- Go to : > Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...
- In the "Create virtual Layer" dialog click on import and choose your
  point dataset
- In the query part make an SQL query like this one : `SELECT year(ACQ_DATE) as year, COUNT(ACQ_DATE) as 'number of incidents' FROM YOUR_LAYER GROUP BY year(ACQ_DATE);` (replace "YOUR_LAYER" by the
  actual layer name of your point dataset)
- Click the "Add" button

This will add a table with two column : year and number of incident, you could easily export this table as CSV by right clicking on it and choose Export > Save Feature As...

[image]

Comment: I have need replace `year(ACQ_DATE)` with `strftime('%Y', ACQ_DATE)` for it to work. My date field is type date in a postgres db